# ImportError: cannot import name 'KeycloakOpenID'

Tags: python, keycloak

How do I fix this error? Python 3.7.3, linux, keycloak==3.0.0

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'KeycloakOpenID' from 'keycloak' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keycloak/__init__.py)
```

cmd:

```
from keycloak import KeycloakOpenID
```

But the command `import keycloak` succeeds. Also I've tried versions 1.0.0, 1.4, 2.0.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Had this same error just now, found the solution. Make sure to install from:

```
pip install keycloak-client
```

Then import it doing:

```
from keycloak.keycloak_openid import KeycloakOpenID

# Configure client
keycloak_openid = KeycloakOpenID(
    server_url="https://localhost:8443/auth/",
    client_id="app_test",
    realm_name="test_realm",
    client_secret_key='SECRET_KEY'
)
```

Comment: I realised this is a different package. But it seems to be the only working one for me. See:
https://github.com/ly798/python-keycloak

Answer (score 0):

I find this package is missing `__init__.py` so I added manually.

```py
import keycloak
print(keycloak.__path__) # --> find where you package located
```

suppose it is located at `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keycloak`

```bash
# go to this directory
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keycloak

touch `__init__.py`
```

```py
# now you can import
from keycloak.keycloak_openid import KeycloakOpenID
```